# Trying to learn Firebase. I'm following "Get to know Firebase for web" codelab and not getting very far

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-codelab

I get to the last step of "Add user sign-in (RSVP)" of the "Get to know Firebase for web" codelab and nothing happens when I click the RSVP button, no errors appear on the console of stackblitz. When I load the page externally so I can use Developer Tools (Chrome) I see this error when I refresh the page. I'm not sure if this is the error that is the root cause or if it is a result of me running outside of the stackblitz environment.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: firebase.initializeApp(...).auth is not a function
    at new Cn (npm.js:418)
    at main (index.js:68)
    at Object.eval (index.js:74)
    at eval (index.js:76)
    at eval (index.js:77)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Qt (webcontainer.3e00eb9f21511f88f1bf57f5f6810512f74d871c.js:15)
    at webcontainer.3e00eb9f21511f88f1bf57f5f6810512f74d871c.js:15
    at U (webcontainer.3e00eb9f21511f88f1bf57f5f6810512f74d871c.js:15)
    at webcontainer.3e00eb9f21511f88f1bf57f5f6810512f74d871c.js:15
```

In any case, when I click the RSVP button, nothing happens. No errors other than the one above upon loading the page. Any clue what I am doing wrong? Or is the codelab not ready for primetime?

Here is the index.js code:

```
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

// Add the Firebase products and methods that you want to use
import { getAuth, EmailAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
import {} from 'firebase/firestore';

import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui';

// Document elements
const startRsvpButton = document.getElementById('startRsvp');
const guestbookContainer = document.getElementById('guestbook-container');

const form = document.getElementById('leave-message');
const input = document.getElementById('message');
const guestbook = document.getElementById('guestbook');
const numberAttending = document.getElementById('number-attending');
const rsvpYes = document.getElementById('rsvp-yes');
const rsvpNo = document.getElementById('rsvp-no');

let rsvpListener = null;
let guestbookListener = null;

let db, auth;

async function main() {
  // Add Firebase project configuration object here
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCxoBt3Lv6Bzds87vmjfOibrm-NQFLM-II",
    authDomain: "fir-web-codelab-806fd.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "fir-web-codelab-806fd",
    storageBucket: "fir-web-codelab-806fd.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "423209299021",
    appId: "1:423209299021:web:ea06da7e0e0efe22700004"
  };

  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  auth = getAuth();
  // FirebaseUI config
  const uiConfig = {
    credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE,
    signInOptions: [
      // Email / Password Provider.
      EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
        // Handle sign-in.
        // Return false to avoid redirect.
        return false;
      }
    }
  };
  const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(auth);

  // Listen to RSVP button clicks
  startRsvpButton.addEventListener("click",
   () => {
        ui.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", uiConfig);
  });
}
main();
```

And here is the index.html:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Firebase Meetup</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/4.0.0/firebaseui.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700|Roboto:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
 
  <!-- <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-images-a61c9.appspot.com/o/firestore.png?alt=media&token=56d039dc-4a6c-477b-a153-a4bb8234646f" /> -->
  <!-- <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-images-a61c9.appspot.com/o/hosting.png?alt=media&token=57c8adb6-08c4-43f7-9395-4c299896a36c" /> -->
  <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-images-a61c9.appspot.com/o/codelab.png?alt=media&token=f45f808c-ce40-4b34-944c-8d8fac00e13d" />

 <section id="event-details-container">
      <h1>Firebase Meetup</h1>

      <p><i class="material-icons">calendar_today</i> October 30</p>
      <p><i class="material-icons">location_city</i> San Francisco</p>
      <!-- ADD THE RSVP BUTTON HERE -->
      <button id="startRsvp">RSVP</button>
  </section>

  <hr>

  <section id="firebaseui-auth-container"></section>

  <section id="description-container">
      <h2>What we'll be doing</h2>
      <p>Join us for a day full of Firebase Workshops and Pizza!</p>
  </section>

  <section id="guestbook-container">
  </section>

</div>
</body>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the `<script>` element

Answer (score 0):

You're using the new v9 version of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, which is quite different from previous versions.

For full details on this, see the detailed [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/837) on Github.

There seems to be an early release version that can work, mentioned [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/837#issuecomment-902260069).

Answer (score 0):

For me I just changed the firebase version to "firebase": "9.6.7" in package.json or change it to latest version https://firebase.google.com/support/releases